# Finding all matching records in mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

This statement is returning only first match record, but I want to get all matching records.

```
var checkStatus = dbx.CONTACTS.FirstOrDefault(chk => status == chk.STATUS)
```

I also tried this

```
var checkStatus = dbx.CONTACTS.All(chk => status == chk.STATUS);
```

but not get required result
also tell how I can receive list of records in jquery function

Comment: `dbx.CONTACTS.Where(chk => status == chk.STATUS);`

Answer (score 1):

`FirstOrDefaul` will return you `first` matching object or `null` if not found

`All` will return `true` if all objects match your condition or return `false` instead

```
var checkStatus = dbx.CONTACTS.Where(chk => status == chk.STATUS);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var checkStatus = dbx.CONTACTS.Where(chk => status == chk.STATUS).ToList()
```